# Render Input with type checkbox already checked

Tags: html, angular

I am doing a project on Angular + TypeScript, and I want to render a  with type=checkbox already checked , I try everything , in the CSS I have pseudo class :checked but I do not know how to trigger it in the HTML

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FX6O.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLzft.png)

I tried ngModel but it cant be used on input , checked = isChecked or true , tried [defaultChecked]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to [bind attribute](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding) `checked` of HTML checbox input to the your selected value

```html
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="userData!['favorites']!.includes(product)"/>
```

Comment: that is the same as [checked]="true" and it doesn't work for me

Comment: @RobertIvanov here is an example for it working
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vxxdtn

Comment: This doesn't work to me and  I think it has something to do with the css , but I still can not figure this out

Comment: @RobertIvanov can you try to edit the stackblitz example to regenerate the error you face?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sx8xfu?file=src%2Fglobal_styles.css

I want the heart to spawn red and checked @fujy

Comment: I just changed it to `<input type="checkbox" [checked]='true' >`, and it worked!

Comment: it did work now , ok I am confused ...... thank you anyways.